# Insert Image in normal java coding

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.Image;



class comparision{

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    File file= new File("C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\projek\\projekcodingjava\\JavaApplication22\\src\\training_1_D.png");



    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
 int width = image.getWidth(null);
    int height = image.getHeight(null);
int[][] clr=  new int[width][height];
File files= new File("C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\projek\\projekcodingjava\\JavaApplication22\\src\\training_1_DB.png");
    BufferedImage images = ImageIO.read(files);
 int widthe = images.getWidth(null);
    int heighte = images.getHeight(null);
int[][] clre=  new int[widthe][heighte];
int smw=0;
int smh=0;
int p=0;


//CALUCLATING THE SMALLEST VALUE AMONG WIDTH AND HEIGHT
if(width>widthe){ smw =widthe;}
else {smw=width;}
if(height>heighte){smh=heighte;}
else {smh=height;}



//CHECKING NUMBER OF PIXELS SIMILARITY
for(int a=0;a<smw;a++){
for(int b=0;b<smh;b++){
clre[a][b]=images.getRGB(a,b);
clr[a][b]=image.getRGB(a,b);
if(clr[a][b]==clre[a][b]) {
    p=p+1;
/*              { //to set if color match between two image (image A and Image B), appear BLACK
                    red = 0;
                         green = 0;
                            blue = 0;

                }
                else
                { //to set if color dont match between two image, appear WHITE
                    red = 255;
                            green = 255;
                                blue = 255;
                }

                pixel_data[color++] = (red << 16) | (green << 8 ) | blue);*/
}
}}

float w,h=0;
if(width>widthe) {w=width;}
else {w=widthe;}
if(height>heighte){ h = height;}
else{h = heighte;}
float s = (smw*smh);
//CALUCLATING PERCENTAGE
float x =(100*p)/s;

System.out.println("THE PERCENTAGE SIMILARITY IS APPROXIMATELY ="+x+"%");
long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("TIME TAKEN IS ="+(stop-start));

  }

   //I WANT TO APPEAR THE IMAGE HERE. RETURN BLACK PIXEL IF PIXEL MATCH BETWEEN TWO IMAGE (IMAGE A AND IMAGE B) AND RETURN WHITE IF PIXEL DOSNT MATCH



}
```

I want to insert picture on the output in this coding..
This coding calculate comparison percentage & i want to add image below the percentage output...

That image will be generated by this rules :
1. if comparison of two image match, black pixel will appear.
2. If comparison of two image doesn't match, white pixel appear

How to insert image generated by this rules using java..?

Comment: If you want a GUI program, you should search for Java Swing or JavaFX.

Comment: if someone can convert this code to gui code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function to which you can pass the path of your image file to output it :-

```
// the imports required
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

//paste this function in your class and call it when you want to display image

public void showImage(String path_to_image)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setResizable(false);
    ImageIcon myImage = new ImageIcon(path_to_image);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(myImage));

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

take two images with white and black and then  in the end where you want it to appear ("//I WANT TO APPEAR THE IMAGE HERE. RETURN BLACK PIXEL IF PIXEL MATCH BETWEEN TWO IMAGE (IMAGE A AND IMAGE B) AND RETURN WHITE IF PIXEL DOSNT MATCH") put an if statement that checks the percentage match that is :-

```
if(x == 100) // means 100 % match as per your code
{
  showImage("Black.png"); // path to black pic
}
else
{
  showImage("White.png"); // path to white pic
}
```

Comment: its work, but i want to do comparison two images percentage & i want to add image below the percentage output...according to my code.